# Create dictionary using list values and pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, loops, dictionary, iterator

I have below list of FullCompanyName,

List_FullCompanyName = ['Google','Microsoft','Accenture']

Input Data is in Dataframe as mentioned below

| CompanyNamecode | DebitAmount | FullCompanyName | CreditAmount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| xyzGoog | 100 | zm |  |
| abcMicrosof | 200 | zx |  |
| xcdAccentu | 300 | qt |  |
| working123 |  | Google | 52 |
| next45 |  | Microsoft | 500 |
| parlell54 |  | Accenture | 95 |

Based on the string value of 'FullCompanyName' find the partial string match in  'CompanyNamecode' column and apply the formula for corresponding partial-string matched records, amount = CreditAmount - DebitAmount.

If a FullCompanyName name is less than 3 characters ignore(ex zm,zx,qt) for string match and also, ignore records with CompanyNamecode if it does not contains a partial string(ex next45,parlell54).
Example:
'FullCompanyName' = 'Google' find the partial string match in  'CompanyNamecode' = 'Goog'. For matching with CompanyNamecode column value use rstrip() and apply the formula Amount = 52-100

Expected output with a dictionary,

Amount_Dict = { FullCompanyName:Amount},

Amount_Dict = {'Google': -48, 'Microsoft': 300, 'Accenture':-205}

Answer (score 1):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from difflib import SequenceMatcher

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['CompanyNamecode', 'DebitAmount', 'FullCompanyName', 'CreditAmount'],
                  data=[['xyzGoog', 100, pd.NA, pd.NA],
                        ['abcMicrosof', 200, pd.NA, pd.NA],
                        ['xcdAccentu', 300, pd.NA, pd.NA],
                        [pd.NA, pd.NA, 'Google', 52],
                        [pd.NA, pd.NA, 'Microsoft', 500],
                        [pd.NA, pd.NA, 'Accenture', 95]
                        ]
                  )

code = df['CompanyNamecode'].dropna()
fullname = df['FullCompanyName'].dropna()

d = {}
for ix, fn in fullname.iteritems():
    matches = [SequenceMatcher(a=fn, b=cd).find_longest_match(0, len(fn), 0, len(cd)).size for cd in code]
    best_match = np.argmax(matches)
    d[fn] = df['CreditAmount'][ix] - df['DebitAmount'][best_match]
    code.drop(best_match)

print(d)  # --> {'Google': -48, 'Microsoft': 300, 'Accenture': -205}
```

Comment: I have some other doubts, can you come to chat please @Lior Cohen

Comment: please detail your doubts

Comment: Added more details to the problem statement @Lior Cohen

Comment: it is a customized problem. So didn't give the details initially, not to confuse the problem.

Comment: Can someone explain to me the reason for the downvote?. It helps me to post next time with proper information

Comment: yoo should ask this as a comment in your question and not here.

Comment: you asked me to provide more details. So instead of providing detailed information again in a comment, I modified the post details. in comments difficult to explain the problem of dataframe

Comment: Going forward, I will follow this. is the question clear now

Comment: Thanks. After some modifications, it worked @Lior Cohen